# fetching xml data from webservice using Soap client in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap-client

I have a web service, [link](http://empblr.dyndns.org/CentralHomeDelivery_Mob/Service.asmx)

I am fetching  xml data from one of its method `GetAllCategory` using following code,

```
 $client = new SoapClient("http://empblr.dyndns.org/CentralHomeDelivery_Mob/Service.asmx?wsdl");
         $result = $client->GetAllCategory();
         print_r( $client);
```

There are 3 child nodes in output xml, `<id> <name> <description>`
When I print $client, data from all nodes is printed.
What I want to know is two things :

1.How to store data from each node to each array.

2.In another method `GetAlladdress` I need to pass a value, which is user id.How can I achieve it?

This is im geting when var_dumb, object(stdClass)[16]
  public 'GetAlladdressResult' => 
    object(stdClass)[17]
      public 'schema' => string ' string '64336176asdf12345632256asdf 2ANDOLANA CIRCLEMysore

Thank you....

Answer (score 0):

If the returned value is a simple string you could use

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($client);
```

The values of the childs can now be accessed as follows:

```
$xml->id
```

you can get more information here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: I cannot find any information about the method GetAllContent is there any documentation for this?

Can you post the output of the print_r($client) ?

Comment: actually, GetAllCategory is a user defined method in webservice

Comment: Okay sorry I cannot reproduce that in any way or something. If you can figure out how to get the xml-content as a string you can use the method described above.